# how to make select drop-down default select using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have two select options one is dependent to other, One is country other is state so when I select Country I am changing state as well, which was working fine previously, but now as per my requirement I want to default select one country and show its cities which is also fine.

**Issue is**

here in my code I Have made England as default selected, but when I am again selected other option suppose India, it is not selecting India.

I don't know why this issue is showing up

**What I have done**

```
  const [selected_country, setselected_country] = useState("England");
  const [selected_state, setselected_state] = useState("London");
```

Creating states for default selected as above, after this

```
 <select
    name="Country"
    value={selected_country}
    onChange={(e) => onchange_device(e.target.value)}
  >
    {data.map((li, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={li.country}>
        {li.country}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

this is how I am looping through countries of my data

```
<select name="city" value={selected_state}>
    {cityOptions.map((city, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={city.city_name}>
        {city.city_name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

the Above one is to set default cities.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

[My code sandbox for better understanding](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-mountain-y47ns?file=/src/App.js:1165-1383)

Comment: You have controlled selects, but you never change their `value` to the newly selected one. This is why in your codesandbox, the `set*` functions have red squiggly lines under them: you're never using them. You need to insert `setselected_country(country);` in your onchange handler.

Comment: @ChrisG Ya I changed that but, the cities is still behaving the same, could u please help me with some example

Comment: Your city select has no `onChange` listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes,

1. Changed data[1] in line 40. Because on page load, England was selected, but states were from India.

```
const [cityOptions, setCityOptions] = useState(data[1].cities);
```

2. Added an `onChange` handler to the select dropdown in line 61.

```
<select name="city" value={selected_state} onChange={e => setselected_state(e.target.value)}>
```